# vlc dshow:// how to limit playback time

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player, directshow

I want to use VLC media player to record from an USB TV receiver. I would like to schedule when to record, but calling vlc from the command line:

```
vlc -Idummy dshow:// --sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,audio=mp2a}:standard{access=file,dst=fromtv.mpg}
```

What I'm missing is a way to limit the time this command will run. I understand dshow:// is an entry on the playlist, and that VLC is working it's way down the playlist, but it will reading from dshow:// because it is an input device.

Is there a way to limit the *runtime length* of `dshow://` on the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
--run-time=<float>        Run time
    The stream will run till this position (in seconds).
```

and perhaps set `vlc:\\quit` as the next command.

Comment: I'm not sure what the time displayed for a dshow stream is, but it makes `--stop-time` unusable, `--run-time` works though, so I accept this answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Stijn: Aangepast! Veel plezier... :)